# Child forms not getting minimized along with the parent forms....?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I have made a project on Library management system using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 and Sql server 2005 .I have used MDiParent form in this project, from where I can click on the menu item to open the desired form.

I am now able to open the child forms in the main window background.Now what happens is When I click on one menu Item it open in the parent form background.I am able to open all child forms corresponding to the click event in the MenuToolStrip ...all in the Parent form
Now the problem is that I cannot minimize child forms when I minimize Parent form..I want child forms also to minimize along with the Parent form..
Also are child forms still not attached to the parent Form is also my question here.....

Comment: Show the code you're using to open the window

Comment: I'm using .show() property of the form to open the forms i.e formname.show()

Comment: It's better if you ask another question, instead of editing the old one. So people will see the old questions and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `Form` property `ShowInTaskbar` .

```
Form blah = new Form();
blah.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

Or just choose the form in the designer, and change the property to false;

Comment: Now what happens is When I click on one menu Item it open in the parent form background but when I go to click on other menu items, the forms previously opened in the background disappears, How to freeze that previously opened forms in run time

Comment: It doesn't disappear, it's just underneath it

Comment: @Yochai Timmer sorry to ask you again ....I still want a bit modification here in the Parent Form...what happens is when I minimize the my Parent form the child child forms don't get minimized with the Parent form. I want child forms also to be minimized with it. Are child forms still not attached to the parent Form is also my question here.....

Answer (score 2):

You sure you are using MDI properly?
The child form should never go out of bound of the parent form.
The main parent form should have a property **IsMdiContainer**, set it to true.
The child form's **MdiParent** property should then be set to the instance of the parent form.
Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mdiformstutorial.aspx).

Comment: IsMdiContainer property is set it to true for the main parent form .How to change mdi property of child forms....as u mentioned..? @ Henddry Ten

Comment: I think you need to do that programatically. Please check the link.

Comment: When you create the child form, just before you show() it. Set the property. Check the link.

Comment: Thanks Henry I figured out the code and got it working for me ....thanks for the help ...

Comment: I used Dim whatever As New form
        whatever.MdiParent = Me
        whatever.Show() and it worked thanks